# Unable to install a playstore app on galaxy s4 mini

Tags: android, installation, google-play

I recently made an Android app in Xamarin (c#) an signed the apk manually.
After that, I uploaded this apk on the playstore.

I heard from a few users that they were unable to install it on the Galaxy
s4 with Android 4.2.2. But some users with the same device were able to install it perfectly.

The minimum required version for my application is 4.0 ...

The user who were unable to install it, say that nothing happens after pressing on the install button, they also couldn't find the app in the store, i had to give them a link. They also had more than enough memory on their device

What could be the problem?

Comment: Could you show your command line how you sign the app? I guess I know the reason for that.

Comment: I did it exactly like the info in this url http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html
section "sign your app manually"

Comment: Try adding `-digestalg SHA1 -sigalg MD5withRSA` to your command line while signing the app. Let me know if this sloves your problem.

Comment: Ok thanks i wil certainly try it.